# How to make the app icon on a Search View act as a filter?

Tags: android, quickaction

Basically, I want to reproduce the following feature:

[image]

Clicking on the app icon brings up a `QuickActionBar` that hosts the different possible search filters.

Does the API support this out of the box or do I have to do it myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the apps I've worked on, we've implemented our own UI for those. It's not built in.

http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/ is a good resource that I've bookmarked on how to do it.

https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction is the code.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I knew about all the different projects available to build a QuickActionBar (I personally use Greendroid), but I somehow hoped that there was an attribute available in the Searchable Configuration for instance that could do this (even if I have read the documentation for it, many times).

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there is not. =(